# activemq with spring, enabling a mirrored queue

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Below is a straight forward spring supported activemq configuration, I didn't have much trouble with that as I have followed the documentation. Basicly there is a queue to whom a producer sends messages to using the jmsTemplate, the configuration is as follows, it is tested and I have no problems with it :

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL"
                value="${activemq.brokerUrl}" />
            <property name="sendTimeout"
                value="${activemq.sendTimeout}" />
            <property name="prefetchPolicy">
                <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
                    <property name="queuePrefetch" value="0" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

```
<amq:queue id="classifiedEventSink"
    physicalName="${activemq.classifiedEventSink.producer}" />

<bean id="jmsTemplateClassifiedEventSink"
    class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">

    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="classifiedEventSink" />
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
</bean>
```

Now keeping this configuration I want to make this a mirrored queue in which, everytime a producer adds a message to the queue, I want that message to be broadcast on a topic. The trick is to make the configuration on spring, since I am having difficulty finding examples. Can you point me towards any direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in the ActiveMQ broker config as shown here: http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html